# Filtering data with checkbox , how should I do it?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, filter

I'm trying to filter the data I retrieve from a web service and I'm trying to do some filtering of the data retrieved based on the category checkbox checked by the users. Here is a sample of my code for my MainActivity:

```
    package com.example.fambond;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private class CheckBoxListener implements OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View aV) {
            String newLine = "\n";
            String boxesChecked = "";
            String boxInput = "";
            if (a.isChecked()) {
                boxesChecked = boxesChecked + a.getText() + newLine;
                boxInput = boxInput + "education";
            }
            if (b.isChecked()) {
                boxesChecked = boxesChecked + b.getText() + newLine;
                boxInput =  boxInput + "," + "festivals_parades";
            }
            if (c.isChecked()) {
                boxesChecked = boxesChecked + c.getText() + newLine;
                boxInput = boxInput + "," + "sports";
            }
            if (d.isChecked()) {
                boxesChecked = boxesChecked + d.getText() + newLine;
                boxInput =  boxInput + "," + "attractions";
            }
            if (e.isChecked()) {
                boxesChecked = boxesChecked + e.getText() + newLine;
                boxInput =  boxInput + "," +"performing_arts";
            }
            if (f.isChecked()) {
                boxesChecked = boxesChecked + f.getText() + newLine;
                boxInput = boxInput + "," + "community" ;
            }
            if (boxesChecked.length() == 0) {
                boxesChecked = "No CheckBoxes Checked";         
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, boxInput, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    private CheckBox a;
    private CheckBox b;
    private CheckBox c;
    private CheckBox d;
    private CheckBox e;
    private CheckBox f;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setWidgetReference();
        setOnClickListeners();
    }

    private void setWidgetReference() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        a = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        b = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        c = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        d = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        e = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
        f = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
    }

    private void setOnClickListeners() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CheckBoxListener aListener = new CheckBoxListener();
        a.setOnClickListener(aListener);
        b.setOnClickListener(aListener);
        c.setOnClickListener(aListener);
        d.setOnClickListener(aListener);
        e.setOnClickListener(aListener);
        f.setOnClickListener(aListener);
    }

}
```

This is the category link I got from the webservice: http://api.evdb.com/rest/categories/list?app_key=rDkKF6nSx6LjWTDR

Comment: so what kind of help you want??

Comment: to display data from ws ...i suggest you to use listview with checkbox..and pass data as per selected or checked checkboxes...check this link   http://goo.gl/sFNoc

Comment: I suggest not to retrieve data first. what you need to do is listen to which checkboxes are checked then after an action is done pass the data with the following information about the checkboxes which are checked. then the filtering will be done on the webservice instead on the device itself. It is much faster than what you're trying to achive. In case you really need to do it that way. I suggest storing the retrieved data first on your SQLite database, do filtering then output.

Comment: hmm i wants to know what should i do to the checkbox in order to make the filtering, or is it the button that i have to configure?

Comment: i wants the checkboxes output to be display in the link like for example, if the user checked on the education and sports, the link will change from 
[link]http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search/?app_key=rDkKF6nSx6LjWTDR&category=? 
into 
[link]http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search/?app_key=rDkKF6nSx6LjWTDR&category=learning_education,festivals_parades,